# Bounded Observable Universe; is there an object we once could see but can no longer?

Tags: universe

If the universe is expanding faster than the speed of light, then there will be objects (matter or energy or whatever) that previously could be seen, but no longer can be seen, precisely because the universe is expanding faster than the speed of light.

Is there such an object that we can no longer see, though previously we could see it?

Comment: different but related question: [Bounded Observable Universe and General Relativity](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36545/7982)

Comment: Come back in a billion years, and someone may be able to answer your question.

Comment: The classic paper on this topic is [Expanding Confusion: common misconceptions of cosmological horizons and the superluminal expansion of the Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808) by Davis & Lineweaver (2003). They also wrote a [Scientific American article](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/TamaraDavis/papers/SciAm_BigBang.pdf), which is a bit easier to read, and there's more related material on Tamara Davis's website.

Comment: Expansion not only carries galaxies away from us, but also carries light toward us. This means that we are in fact (easily) able to see galaxies that are receding faster than light. [Galaxies don't disappear](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19909/5264) and [information cannot leave the observable Universe](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14336/5264).